# Adding a background image for a basic Flask App?

Tags: python, css, flask

I have created a flask app that predicts heart disease, but I'm trying to just add a background image using the following code:

```
body{
    background-image:url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract- 
    background-with-a-watercolor- 
    texture_1048-2144.jpg');
    }
```

and

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ 
url_for('static',filename='body.css') }}"
```

I have the body code as a css file, but where do I place the <link? section?

Answer (score 0):

**Update your css to this**

```
body{
   height:100vh;
   background-image:url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-backgroundwith-a-watercolor- texture_1048-2144.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do I place the <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ 
url_for('static',filename='body.css') }}" would that go in thr flask app file, html?

Comment: yes, in the browser html is rendered so in order to load your css you should put all your static files there.

Comment: Mark it is an answer if your problem is solved, Thank You!